# Web 8.5 Deployer Configuration - deployer-config.xml - Deployer fails to start

Tags: deployer, deployer-conf

I am trying to configure the Deployer service in SDL Web 8.5 in the new way and  after following all the steps in the SDL documentation. I am not able to start  the service even though I have configured the Deployer stateStore.

Can someone share with me a working `Deployer-config.xml`? Without the sensitive data please? 
See my Deployer-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Deployer xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="8.5" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/deployer-conf.xsd">
<Pipelines>
    <Pipeline Id="Tridion-Bootstrap" Action="TridionBootstrap" Verb="Content,Prepare,Commit">
        <Steps>
            <Step Id="TridionUnzipStep"/>
        </Steps>
    </Pipeline>
    <Pipeline Id="Tridion-Wait" Action="Deploy,Undeploy" Verb="Wait">
        <Steps>
            <Step Id="TridionWaitStep"/>
        </Steps>
    </Pipeline>
    <Pipeline Id="Tridion-Process-Deploy" Action="Deploy" Verb="Process">
        <Steps>
            <Step Id="SchemaDeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.SchemaDeploy" Type="SchemaDeploy"/>
            </Step>
            <Step Id="PageDeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageDeploy" Type="PageDeploy">
                    <Transformer Class="com.tridion.transformer.TCDLDefaultTransformer"/>
                </Module>
            </Step>
            <Step Id="BinaryDeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.BinaryDeploy" Type="BinaryDeploy"/>
            </Step>
            <Step Id="ComponentDeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.ComponentDeploy" Type="ComponentDeploy"/>
            </Step>
            <Step Id="TemplateDeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.TemplateDeploy" Type="TemplateDeploy"/>
            </Step>
            <Step Id="PublicationDeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.PublicationDeploy" Type="PublicationDeploy"/>
            </Step>
            <Step Id="TaxonomyDeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.TaxonomyDeploy" Type="TaxonomyDeploy"/>
            </Step>
            <Step Id="ComponentPresentationDeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.ComponentPresentationDeploy" Type="ComponentPresentationDeploy">
                    <Transformer Class="com.tridion.transformer.TCDLDefaultTransformer"/>
                </Module>
            </Step>
            <Step Id="StructureGroupDeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.StructureGroupDeploy" Type="StructureGroupDeploy"/>
            </Step>
        </Steps>
    </Pipeline>
    <Pipeline Id="Tridion-Process-Undeploy" Action="Undeploy" Verb="Process">
        <Steps>
            <Step Id="PageUndeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageUndeploy" Type="PageUndeploy"/>
            </Step>
            <Step Id="ComponentPresentationUndeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.ComponentPresentationUndeploy" Type="ComponentPresentationUndeploy"/>
            </Step>
            <Step Id="TaxonomyUndeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.TaxonomyUndeploy" Type="TaxonomyUndeploy"/>
            </Step>
            <Step Id="StructureGroupUndeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.StructureGroupUndeploy" Type="StructureGroupUndeploy"/>
            </Step>
        </Steps>
    </Pipeline>
    <Pipeline Id="Tridion-PreCommit-TX" Action="Deploy,Undeploy" Verb="PreCommit">
        <Steps>
            <Step Id="TridionPreCommitStep"/>
        </Steps>
    </Pipeline>
    <Pipeline Id="Tridion-Commit-TX" Action="Deploy,Undeploy" Verb="Commit">
        <Steps>
            <Step Id="TridionCommitStep">
                <RetryPoint PipelineId="Tridion-PreCommit-TX" StepId="TridionPreCommitStep"/>
            </Step>
        </Steps>
    </Pipeline>
    <Pipeline Id="Tridion-Rollback-TX" Action="Deploy,Undeploy" Verb="Rollback">
        <Steps>
            <Step Id="TridionRollbackStep"/>
        </Steps>
    </Pipeline>
    <Pipeline Id="Tridion-Cleanup" Action="Deploy,Undeploy" Verb="*">
        <Steps>
            <Step Id="TridionCleanupStep"/>
        </Steps>
    </Pipeline>
</Pipelines>

<!-- Binary Storage configuration -->
<BinaryStorage Id="PackageStorage" Adapter="FileSystem">
    <Property Name="Path" Value="D:/SDLWebStageDeployer/Binary/"/>
</BinaryStorage>

 <State>
    <Storage Adapter="mssql" driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" >
        <Property Name="host" Value="xxxxxxx"/>
        <Property Name="port" Value="XXX"/>
        <Property Name="database" Value="Tridion_Broker_Web8"/>
         <Property Name="user" Value="StateStoreUser"/>
         <Property Name="password" Value="xxxxxx"/>  
    </Storage>
</State>

<!-- Queues configuration -->
<Queues>
    <!-- Queues default configuration for Filesystem-->
    <Queue Default="true" Verbs="Content" Adapter="FileSystem" Id="ContentQueue">
        <Property Name="Destination" Value="D:/SDLWebStageDeployer/Queues/"/>
        <!-- Optional property to set number of workers
        <Property Name="Workers" Value="11"/> -->
    </Queue>
    <Queue Verbs="Commit,Rollback" Adapter="FileSystem" Id="CommitQueue">
        <Property Name="Destination" Value="D:/SDLWebStageDeployer/Queues/FinalTX"/>
        <!-- Optional property to set number of workers
        <Property Name="Workers" Value="11"/> -->
    </Queue>
    <Queue Verbs="Prepare" Adapter="FileSystem" Id="PrepareQueue">
        <Property Name="Destination" Value="D:/SDLWebStageDeployer/Queues/Prepare"/>
        <!-- Optional property to set number of workers
        <Property Name="Workers" Value="11"/> -->
    </Queue>
    <Adapter Id="FileSystem">
        <!-- optional property to set polling interval-->
        <Property Name="LocationPollingInterval" Value="2s"/> 
    </Adapter>


    <!-- Workers configuration properties -->
    <Workers>
        <!-- Optional configuration properties-->
        <Property Name="QueuePollingInterval" Value="2s"/>
        <Property Name="RetriesInterval" Value="100ms"/>
        <Property Name="MaxRetries" Value="11"/>
        <Property Name="Cleanup" Value="true"/> 
    </Workers>
</Queues>

<!-- RMI Channel Port -->
<!--
    <RMIChannel ListenerPort="1050"/>
-->
<!-- License Path -->
<License Path="D:/SDLWebServices/Deployer/Stage/config/cd_licenses.xml" />
```

===============================
Below is the error I get in my log file when I start the service.

> =============================================================================
>   2017-06-08 12:41:11,221 DEBUG AmbientDataConfig - Configured ADF cookie prefix: TAFContext.
>   2017-06-08 12:41:11,221 DEBUG AmbientDataContext - Setting current ambient data context: com.tridion.ambientdata.web.WebContext
>   2017-06-08 12:41:11,237 INFO  HTTPHeaderProcessor - The DigestKey was not configured, so no digest will be added to the headers and cookies and they won't be validated!
>   2017-06-08 12:41:11,237 DEBUG VersionFilter - CIS version is 8.5.0.1013
>   2017-06-08 12:41:11,268 DEBUG XMLConfigurationReaderImpl - Reading configuration from source: 'deployer-conf.xml'
>   2017-06-08 12:41:11,331 DEBUG StatePropertiesConfigurer - Loading State configuration
>   2017-06-08 12:41:11,331 DEBUG AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter - Destroying Ambient Data Framework filter
>   2017-06-08 12:41:11,331 DEBUG AmbientDataContext - Setting current ambient data context: null
>   2017-06-08 12:41:11,471 ERROR SpringApplication - Application startup failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/sdl/delivery/spring/configuration/StateStoreDBConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/sdl/delivery/spring/configuration/StateStoreDBConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is com.sdl.delivery.configuration.ConfigurationException: Placeholder value is found. Please specify valid configuration for State Store database
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1023)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sdl.delivery.service.ServiceContainer.main(ServiceContainer.java:87)
>       at com.sdl.delivery.service.WinServiceContainer.start(WinServiceContainer.java:27)
>       at com.sdl.delivery.service.WinServiceContainer.main(WinServiceContainer.java:44)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/sdl/delivery/spring/configuration/StateStoreDBConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is com.sdl.delivery.configuration.ConfigurationException: Placeholder value is found. Please specify valid configuration for State Store database
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1023)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1128)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
>       ... 23 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is com.sdl.delivery.configuration.ConfigurationException: Placeholder value is found. Please specify valid configuration for State Store database
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
>       ... 36 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: com.sdl.delivery.configuration.ConfigurationException: Placeholder value is found. Please specify valid configuration for State Store database
>       at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.jpa.config.StatePropertiesConfigurer.getStateProperties(StatePropertiesConfigurer.java:65)
>       at com.sdl.delivery.spring.configuration.StateStoreDBConfiguration.dataSource(StateStoreDBConfiguration.java:39)
>       at com.sdl.delivery.spring.configuration.StateStoreDBConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ee3c24c6.CGLIB$dataSource$2()
>       at com.sdl.delivery.spring.configuration.StateStoreDBConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ee3c24c6$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a19d4295.invoke()
>       at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
>       at com.sdl.delivery.spring.configuration.StateStoreDBConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ee3c24c6.dataSource()
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
>       ... 37 common frames omitted
>   2017-06-08 12:41:11,471 ERROR ServiceContainer - Could not load ServiceContainer
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sdl.delivery.service.ServiceContainer.main(ServiceContainer.java:87)
>       at com.sdl.delivery.service.WinServiceContainer.start(WinServiceContainer.java:27)
>       at com.sdl.delivery.service.WinServiceContainer.main(WinServiceContainer.java:44)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/sdl/delivery/spring/configuration/StateStoreDBConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/sdl/delivery/spring/configuration/StateStoreDBConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is com.sdl.delivery.configuration.ConfigurationException: Placeholder value is found. Please specify valid configuration for State Store database
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1023)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
>       ... 7 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/sdl/delivery/spring/configuration/StateStoreDBConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is com.sdl.delivery.configuration.ConfigurationException: Placeholder value is found. Please specify valid configuration for State Store database
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1023)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1128)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
>       ... 23 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is com.sdl.delivery.configuration.ConfigurationException: Placeholder value is found. Please specify valid configuration for State Store database
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
>       ... 36 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: com.sdl.delivery.configuration.ConfigurationException: Placeholder value is found. Please specify valid configuration for State Store database
>       at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.jpa.config.StatePropertiesConfigurer.getStateProperties(StatePropertiesConfigurer.java:65)
>       at com.sdl.delivery.spring.configuration.StateStoreDBConfiguration.dataSource(StateStoreDBConfiguration.java:39)
>       at com.sdl.delivery.spring.configuration.StateStoreDBConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ee3c24c6.CGLIB$dataSource$2()
>       at com.sdl.delivery.spring.configuration.StateStoreDBConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ee3c24c6$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a19d4295.invoke()
>       at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
>       at com.sdl.delivery.spring.configuration.StateStoreDBConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ee3c24c6.dataSource()
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
>       ... 37 common frames omitted
>   2017-06-08 12:41:11,471 INFO  WinServiceContainer - Spring application container started

Comment: Can you share your Deployer-config.xml & storage config files here

Comment: @Velmurugan, I have  updated my post and added my deployer-config.xml,

Comment: Can you use this driver name instead of they one you have now.
driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource"

Comment: @Velmurugan, Just tried that and got the same error, wonder why it  can not read the state store even when it is configured.

Comment: From the logs it looks like you have some property set to placeholder (like  ${dbhost} ) and the value could not be resolved. Can you please check if these values are set properly ?

Comment: But I don't, see my deployer-config.xml in my original post.

Comment: probably your password (or any masked data) contains $. That could be the reason for this particular error.

Comment: @vinayknl,  that was the problem, my password has a $ in it, removing this fixed it. many thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Great...adding this as answer if someone has similar issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60384/discussion-between-headoo-and-vinayknl).

Comment: btw - there was no need to remove the '$' instaed you can escape it in password with "\$" as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was that if one of the property value (for example password) contains `$`, then there is a problem resolving the value which results in this exception.

Fixing this should resolve the error with loading State store configuration.